# Google TV Resources and HW/SW to get started

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm going to be working on a Google TV Project soon, and would like to know some good sources to start learning about Google TV.  I have heard about Google TV OS and the SDK but I'd like to start with the latest approach, so I need an update on this.  Is there an active newsgroup just for Google TV?  Also in terms of Hardware what do I need to get started with the latest OS etc.  I have a logitech device but need to know what hardware resources I should get to work with latest Google TV capabilities.

I am particularly interested in what we can purchase now from Samsung to support Google TV and what is in the pipeline?  Since the Logitech device is now dated what should I buy to start testing out Google TV apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google TV Developer site:

https://developers.google.com/tv/

is a good place to get started on developing apps for Google TV. If you have technical questions related to Google TV application development feel free to post them here on StackOverflow.

For information about the Google TV Developer community see here:

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/community

There are no Samsung Google TV devices in the market today. To test Google TV apps you could use any of the available Google TV devices:

http://support.google.com/googletv/?hl=en

You could also use the emulator to test your app:

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator